# Compare elements of array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

```
var getJSON = require('get-json')

var dateToday = new Date();
var dayToday = dateToday.getDate();
var monthToday = dateToday.getMonth() + 1;
var yearToday = dateToday.getFullYear();

const date = yearToday + "-" + monthToday + "-" + dayToday;

getJSON('https://betwatch.fr/getMoney?choice=Match%20Odds&date=' + date)
    .then(function (response) {

        getJSON('https://betwatch.fr/getMoney?choice=Over%2FUnder%202.5%20Goals&date=' + date)
            .then(function (response2) {

                getJSON('https://betwatch.fr/getMoney?choice=Both%20teams%20to%20Score%3F&date=' + date)
                    .then(function (response3) {

                        const IsEmptyArray = arr => !(typeof (arr) === 'object' && arr instanceof Array && arr.length > 0);

                        const getFieldMap = (arr, field) => {
                            arr = (!IsEmptyArray(arr)) ? arr : [];
                            const result = arr.reduce((result, elm) => {
                                const key = elm[field];
                                if (key) {
                                    result[key] = elm;
                                }
                                return result;
                            }, {});
                            return result;
                        };

                        var array1 = JSON.parse(response);
                        var array2 = JSON.parse(response2);
                        var array3 = JSON.parse(response3);

                        const arr1Map = getFieldMap(array1, 'm');
                        const arr2Map = getFieldMap(array2, 'm');
                        const arr3Map = getFieldMap(array3, 'm');
                        const maxArr = (array1.length > array2.length) ? ((array1.length > array3.length) ? array1 : array2) : ((array2.length > array3.length) ? array2 : array3);

                        delete array1;
                        delete array2;
                        delete array3;

                        const matchingObjects = maxArr.reduce((matchingObjects, ele) => {
                            key = ele.m;
                            if (arr1Map[key] && arr2Map[key] && arr3Map[key]) {
                                ele['n_arr'] = [arr1Map[key]['i'], arr2Map[key]['i'], arr3Map[key]['i']]
                                ele['n_arr_vm'] = [arr1Map[key]['vm'], arr2Map[key]['vm'], arr3Map[key]['vm']]
                                matchingObjects.push(ele);
                            }
                            return matchingObjects;
                        }, [])
                        console.log(matchingObjects);
                    }).catch(function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Given these 3 arrays (GOT FROM API) I would like to check for **'m'** in array2 and array3.

If **'m'** is present in all three then return the matching objects.

I tried to do this with the loop but I only get the position matches.

Example: FIRST ARRAY **'m'** = Juventus - Roma present in all three arrays.

I would like to derive the objects **'i'** from the other two always in correspondence with the example matches.

Comment: why not `"Taraji Wadi Al-Nes - Jabal Al Mukaber"`? please add your code.

Comment: I added. From API I get JSON. If I compare with FOR cycle it compares only position.

Answer (score 0):

```
var getJSON = require('get-json')


const IsEmptyArray = arr => !(typeof (arr) === 'object' && arr instanceof Array && arr.length > 0);

const getFieldMap = (arr, field) => {
  arr = (!IsEmptyArray(arr)) ? arr : [];
  const result = arr.reduce((result, elm) => {
    const key = elm[field];
    if (key) {
      result[key] = elm;
    }
    return result;
  }, {});
  return result;
};

const getMatchingObjects = async () => {

  var dateToday = new Date();
  var dayToday = dateToday.getDate();
  var monthToday = dateToday.getMonth() + 1;
  var yearToday = dateToday.getFullYear();

  const date = yearToday + "-" + monthToday + "-" + dayToday;

  const [array1, array2, array3] = await Promise.all(
    [
      getJSON('https://betwatch.fr/getMoney?choice=Match%20Odds&date=' + date),
      getJSON('https://betwatch.fr/getMoney?choice=Over%2FUnder%202.5%20Goals&date=' + date),
      getJSON('https://betwatch.fr/getMoney?choice=Both%20teams%20to%20Score%3F&date=' + date)
    ]
  )

  const arr1Map = getFieldMap(array1, 'm');
  const arr2Map = getFieldMap(array2, 'm');
  const arr3Map = getFieldMap(array3, 'm');
  const maxArr = (array1.length > array2.length) ? ((array1.length > array3.length) ? array1 : array2) : ((array2.length > array3.length) ? array2 : array3);

  delete array1;
  delete array2;
  delete array3;

  const matchingObjects = maxArr.reduce((matchingObjects, ele) => {
    key = ele.m;
    if (arr1Map[key] && arr2Map[key] && arr3Map[key]) {
      const obj = {};
      for (const [k, value] of Object.entries(ele)) {
        let fieldValues; 
        if(value instanceof Array){
          fieldValues = new Set([...arr1Map[key][k], ...arr2Map[key][k], ...arr3Map[key][k]]);
        }else{
          fieldValues = new Set([arr1Map[key][k], arr2Map[key][k], arr3Map[key][k]]);
        }

        if (fieldValues.size === 1) {
          obj[k] = [...fieldValues][0];
        } else {
          obj[`${k}_arr`] = [...fieldValues];
        }
      }
      matchingObjects.push(obj);
    }
    return matchingObjects;
  }, [])

  return matchingObjects;
}

getMatchingObjects().then(resp => {
  console.log(resp);
})
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224549/discussion-on-answer-by-kgangadhar-compare-elements-of-array).